# Efficiently find highest value among objects, and identify the object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, object

Suppose I have 5 objects: `obj1` to `obj5`:

```
obj1.x = 2.7
obj2.x = 0.9
obj3.x = 3.8
obj4.x = 1.2
obj5.x = 0.4
```

How can I find (efficiently) the highest value of `x`, and identify the corresponding `obj`? Here the expected answer would be:

```
x = 3.8, it belongs to obj3
```

By the way, in the actual case, I have `500` objects.

Comment: Do you have them in a list or some sort of data structure?

Comment: I posted a new answer based on the assumption that you identify the objects by their index in a sequence rather than by a unique variable name.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your kind help. Is it possible to sort the objects instead of only finding the max one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list and you need the index of the maximum, you can combine `max` and `enumerate` to make an equivalent to `numpy.argmax` in pure Python:

```
l = [obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]
i = max(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1].x)[0]
```

`i` will be the index containing the maximum value, so you can print it as

```
print('x = {}, belongs to obj{}'.format(l[i].x, i + 1))
```

In the example you gave, `i == 2`, which prints `x = 3.8, belongs to obj3`.

Comment: Thanks @Mad Physicist. Is it possible to sort the objects, instead of only finding the max one?

Comment: You mean using `s = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.x)`?. In that case, the max will just be `s[-1]`. If `l` is a mutable sequence like a `list` (as in my example), you can also do `l.sort(key = lambda x: x.x)`, in which case it will be sorted in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Best to put them in a collection (i.e `list`, `tuple`, ..) and use `max` with [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to grab the object with the max value of `x`:

```
from operator import attrgetter
l = obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5  
o = max(l, key=attrgetter('x'))
```

The value `o` returned now corresponds to the one with the max value for the attribute `x`, i.e `obj3`:

```
o == obj3 # True
```

Ideally, you shouldn't "identify" the object by means of its name, that can easily change and if you have a list that isn't ordered by the name you'd get wrong results.

Instead, you should give the class it was created from another attribute, say`"name"`, and define an `__str__`/`__repr__` for it that prints out the name and the value.

Comment: Nice! Always nice to get to use `attrgetter` :)

Comment: If you want to avoid the import, `key=lambda x: x.x` works just fine as well.

Comment: It's just too bad there is not built-in equivalent to numpy's `argmax` function.

Comment: This has the drawback that it does not retrieve the index of the object.

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot.